# Issues using accepts_nested_attributes_for to update associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a form that updates an association when updating the parent object. I've been trying to use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` option as well as `attr_accessible` but am still running into a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes` error.

Here are my models:

```
class Mastery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mastery_id,
                  :name,
                  :icon,
                  :max_points,
                  :dependency,
                  :tier,
                  :position,
                  :tree,
                  :description,
                  :effects_attributes
  has_many :effects, :as => :affects, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'effects.value'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :effects
end


class Effect < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,
                  :modifier,
                  :value,
                  :affects_id,
                  :affects_type
  belongs_to :affects, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Here's the partial that's rendering the form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [ :manage, resource ], :html => {:class => 'default-manage-form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <% attributes.each do |attr| %>
      <%= f.input attr.to_sym %>
    <% end %>

    <% if resource.respond_to? :effects %>
      <% resource.effects.each do |effect| %>
        <hr>
        <%= f.inputs :modifier, :name, :value, :for => effect %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.actions do %>
      <%= f.action :submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My form is for the Mastery record which contains multiple Effect records. Can anyone see why I'd be running into this error and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I am not getting what are `:manage and :resource` means in your `semantic_form_for`. Can you explain?

Comment: Do you really have :mastery_id in Mastery model or its just a typo?

Comment: @SybariteManoj I did, realized it was an error and removed it.

Comment: @checkit I'm using the `inherited_resources` gem to dynamically pass resources around

Comment: @SybariteManoj Is it bad practice to do so? When I remove it I run into other mass-assignment issues when updating from a form.

Comment: Why would you have mastery_id in Mastery table?

Comment: @SybariteManoj Ah sorry, that is not the database assigned id for that record. It is a string identifier used as a the primary key for associating records between client and server side apps. Its something I manage outside of the DB to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this by doing two things:

1) Changing the form structure to use `fields_for` and

2) Adding `:effects_attributes` to the attr_accessible for the Mastery model

Here's the new form code:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [ :manage, resource ], :html => {:class => 'default-manage-form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <% attributes.each do |attr| %>
      <%= f.input attr.to_sym %>
    <% end %>

    <% if resource.respond_to? :effects %>
      <%= f.fields_for :effects do |b| %>
        <hr>
        <%= b.inputs :modifier, :name, :value %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.actions do %>
      <%= f.action :submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finished model:

```
class Mastery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,
                  :icon,
                  :max_points,
                  :dependency,
                  :tier,
                  :position,
                  :tree,
                  :description,
                  :effects_attributes
  has_many :effects, :as => :affects, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'effects.value'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :effects
end
```